# Windows VBS tell which application is focused

Tags: windows, vbscript, focus

How can I make a script that can tell which application window is currently focused by the user?
Is this possible using vbs?

Say I want a script to know when my browser, or text editor is currently being used.

Comment: Maybe it is just me but 2 upvotes? Someone please tell me how *"This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear"*? Please take a  look at [ask]

Comment: I figured it out using c++, thanks for the help